# Why do the sentences stand?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The proof of $\varnothing \subset A $ is the following:

Let $x$ an element that does not belong to $A$. Then, since $\varnothing$ does not contain any element, $x$ does not belong to $\varnothing$.

Why do we conclude that $C \subset D$, showing that if $x \notin D \rightarrow x \notin C$ ? 
$$$$
Could you also give me some hints how  we could prove that $\varnothing=\{ x: x \neq x \}$ ?

Comment: Should say instead that any $x\in\emptyset$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you maybe know what's the contrapostion of $\varnothing \subset A$ ? :/

Comment: The contrapositive is in my opinion an awkward way to attack this already somewhat awkward assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We conclude that $C\subseteq D$ if we know that $x\notin D\rightarrow x\notin C$, because the definition of $C\subseteq D$ is that $x\in C\rightarrow x\in D$, and $\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ is equivalent to $\lnot\psi\rightarrow\lnot\varphi$.

Namely, if $x$ is not in $D$ means that there is no way that $x\in C$ is the same as saying that if $x\in C$ then it has to be in $D$ as well.

As for the case that $\varnothing=\{x\mid x\neq x\}$, note that if $x$ is any mathematical object then $x=x$.

Comment: How could we prove that $\varphi\rightarrow\psi$ is equivalent to $\lnot\psi\rightarrow\lnot\varphi$? 
$$$$

I see, but how could we prove it formally, that $\varnothing=\{ x| x \neq x \}$ ?

Comment: Well, just write down the truth tables. As for the second case, if $x\in\{x\mid x\neq x\}$, then $x\neq x$. This is impossible, so there is no such $x$.

Comment: Asaf Karagila I see!!! Thank you!!! :-) Could you also tell me if I can prove the sentences: $$$$
$A \subset B \wedge B \subset C \rightarrow A \subset C$
$$$$
$A \subset B \wedge B \subset A \rightarrow A=B$
$$$$
like that?

Comment: - $A \subset B \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$
$B \subset C \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in B \rightarrow x \in C)$

$A \subset B \wedge B \subset C \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \rightarrow x \in C) \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C) \leftrightarrow A \subset C$
$$$$
- $A \subset B \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$
 $B \subset A \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in B \rightarrow x \in A)$
$A \subset B \wedge B \subset A \leftrightarrow \forall x(x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)$
$$$$

Comment: Remember that $\rightarrow$ is not associative. Writing $x\in A\rightarrow x\in B\rightarrow x\in C$ is not a good way to write these things. The second proof is fine.

Comment: Asaf How else could I prove the first sentence?

Comment: One direction of the equivalence at a time.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain it further to me?

Comment: Err, I'm sorry. Note that there is no equivalence here. There's no reason to expect a sequence of $\leftrightarrow$ statements will constitute a proof. Instead try a sequence of inferences. Assume that $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$, and prove that $A\subseteq C$.

Comment: Asaf Kagargila So can't I use the definition of $A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$ ?

Comment: Where did I say that? I said that you **should** use the definition. But you suggest a proof of the form $\varphi\leftrightarrow \ldots\leftrightarrow\psi$. But the statement you are trying to prove is not $\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$. So why are you trying to prove such a statement? Instead, you should prove only the relevant direction of implications.

Comment: So you mean that it is like that?

$$A \subset B \rightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$$
$$B \subset C \rightarrow \forall x(x \in B \to x \in C)$$

$$A \subset B \wedge B \subset C \rightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B \rightarrow x \in C) \rightarrow \forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in C) \rightarrow A \subset C$$

Or have I understood it wrong? Could you explain me why $\leftrightarrow$ does not hold?